# Does anyone need materials on the Rusyn language?

Tags: discussion, resources, languages

In my question here, [Are questions about the Rusyn language stuff accepted here?](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113/are-questions-about-the-rusyn-language-stuff-accepted-here/131?noredirect=1#comment388_131), I asked if there is need in Rusyn dictionaries and learning materials, but nobody wrote anything, so I think that question was not noticed. That is why I again ask it, now with a separate questions. What I can share is:

- "Let's Speak Rusyn ­— Говорім по-руськы" – a Rusyn textbook in English
- "Ruthenian" - another Rusyn textbook in English
- "Словник русинсько-руськый (Русинско-русский словарь) [2007, Керча И.]" - a Rusyn-Russian dictionary
- "Словник русько-русинськый ( Русско-русинский словарь) в 2 томах [2012, Керча И.]" - a Russian-Rusyn dictionary in 2 volumes
- "Русинсько-Украйинсько-Руський и Русско-Украинско-Русинский словарь [2007, Поп Д.]" - a Rusyn-Ukrainian-Russian and Russian-Ukrainian-Rusyn dictionary
- "Печора Н. - Русинськый язык. 1-3 цвiт - 2013" - Rusyn textbooks for the 1-3 grades of Rusyn schools

I do this to see how much people here are interested in Rusyn and to measure the demand for Rusyn-related questions on our Ukrainian Language SE. I will give the link for downloading those books in my answer to this question. Please, vote for the answer, that will be the gauge of the demand for the Rusyn language stuff (votes in Meta do not change the reputation).

Answer (score 2):

IMHO it would be good to create a list with Rusyn-related resources [here](//meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/8).

**As a separate answer**. Because it's quite specific topic. (Not wide-audience resources about Ukrainian language.)

(To explain my vision: I think that all general-purpose links within that wiki-question should be merged into the one wiki-answer. And that sashaeve and bytebuster did a bad thing when failed to do that (either immediately or soon after adding). But very specific-purpose links deserve to within separate answers.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link to download those books on the Rusyn language, it is a Mediafire folder which contains all the books I mentioned: https://www.mediafire.com/folder/cighh2bg9hh7p/RUSYN